# pandas dataframe - remove values from a group with less than X rows

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas

I need to calculate a std mean from a time series (monthly frequence), but i also need to exclude from the calculation the "incomplete" Years (with less then 12 moths)

Numpy/scipy "working" version :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sts

url='http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices'
npdata = np.genfromtxt(url, skip_header=1)
unique_enso_year = [int(value) for value in set(npdata[:, 0])]
nin34 = np.zeros(len(unique_enso_year))
for ind, year in enumerate(unique_enso_year):
    indexes = np.flatnonzero(npdata[:, 0]==year)
    if len(indexes) == 12:
        nin34[ind] = np.mean(npdata[indexes, 9])
    else:
        nin34[ind] = np.nan

nin34x = (nin34 - sts.nanmean(nin34)) / sts.nanstd(nin34)

array([[  1.02250000e+00,   5.15000000e-01,  -6.73333333e-01,
     -7.02500000e-01,   1.16666667e-01,   1.32916667e+00,
     -1.10333333e+00,  -8.11666667e-01,   1.51666667e-01,
      6.42500000e-01,   6.49166667e-01,   3.71666667e-01,
      4.05000000e-01,  -1.98333333e-01,  -4.79166667e-01,
      1.24666667e+00,  -1.44166667e-01,  -1.18166667e+00,
     -8.89166667e-01,  -2.51666667e-01,   7.36666667e-01,
      3.02500000e-01,   3.83333333e-01,   1.19166667e-01,
      1.70833333e-01,  -5.25000000e-01,  -7.35000000e-01,
      3.75000000e-01,  -4.50833333e-01,  -8.30000000e-01,
     -1.41666667e-02,              nan]])
```

Pandas attempt :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

def parse(yr, mon):
    date = datetime(year=int(yr), day=2, month=int(mon))
    return date


url='http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices'
data = pd.read_table(url, sep=' ', header=0, skiprows=0, parse_dates = [['YR', 'MON']], skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0, date_parser=parse)                     
grouped = data.groupby(lambda x: x.year)

zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
transformed = grouped.transform(zscore)
print transformed['ANOM.3'] 

YR_MON
1982-01-02   -0.986922
1982-02-02   -1.179216
1982-03-02   -1.179216
1982-04-02   -0.885119
1982-05-02   -0.376105
1982-06-02    0.087664
1982-07-02   -0.161188
1982-08-02    0.098975
1982-09-02    0.415695
1982-10-02    1.049134
1982-11-02    1.286674
1982-12-02    1.829622
1983-01-02    1.715072
1983-02-02    1.428598
1983-03-02    0.976272
...
2012-03-02   -0.999284
2012-04-02   -0.663736
2012-05-02   -0.063283
2012-06-02    0.572491
2012-07-02    0.961020
2012-08-02    1.314227
2012-09-02    0.925699
2012-10-02    0.537170
2012-11-02    0.660793
2012-12-02   -0.169245
2013-01-02   -1.001483
2013-02-02   -0.924445
2013-03-02    0.462223
2013-04-02    1.386668
2013-05-02    0.077037
Name: ANOM.3, Length: 377, dtype: float64
```

This is not what i want .. because count also 2013 (that has only 5 months)

To extract what i want i need t do something like :

```
(grouped.mean()['ANOM.3'][:-1] - sts.nanmean(grouped.mean()['ANOM.3'][:-1])) / sts.nanstd(grouped.mean()['ANOM.3'][:-1])
```

but this assume that i already k now that the last year was incomplete and then i loose the the np.NAN where i should have the 2013 value

so i was now trying to make a query in pandas like :

```
grouped2 = data.groupby(lambda x: x.year).apply(lambda sdf: sdf if len(sdf) > 11 else None).reset_index(drop=True)
```

That gives me the "right values" .. but  this generated a new dataframe "without index with timestamp" .. i'm sure there is a simply and beauty way to do it.. thanks for any help!

Comment: [ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5843294)

Comment: why do you add `.reset_index(drop=True)`? Without it pandas generates a MultiIndex DataFrame, which includes proper timestamp.

Comment: i tried to set  it to false or remove it, i omitted this pat in the description sorry. It was not the same type of the "original dataframe" :

##
    MultiIndex
    [1982  1982-01-02, 1982-02-02, 1982-03-02, 1982-04-02, 1982-05-02,       1982-06-02, 1982-07-02, 1982-08-02,..., 2012-11-02, 2012-12-02]

##

Instead i should have something like :

    <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
    [1982-01-02 00:00:00, ..., 2012-12-02 00:00:00]
    Length: 372, Freq: None, Timezone: None

Comment: @abudis

I guess what i need is to "convert" the multiIndex to proper pandas timestamp index.

Comment: i tried the following :

* rng = pd.date_range(grouped2.index[0][1], grouped2.index[-1][1], freq="M")
* #ts = pd.DataFrame(grouped2.values, index=rng)
* rng

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1982-01-31 00:00:00, ..., 2012-11-30 00:00:00]
Length: 371, Freq: M, Timezone: None

It almost works .. it is missing the last value for december 2012

Comment: out of topic: what's that `jist` command in your notebook?

Comment: IIUC you can `filter`:  `grouped2 = data.groupby(lambda x: x.year).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 11).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this way :

```
import pandas as pd

url='http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices'

ts_raw = pd.read_table(url, 
                        sep=' ', 
                        header=0, 
                        skiprows=0, 
                        parse_dates = [['YR', 'MON']], 
                        skipinitialspace=True, 
                        index_col=0, 
                        date_parser=parse)                     
ts_year_group = ts_raw.groupby(lambda x: x.year).apply(lambda sdf: sdf if len(sdf) > 11 else None) 
ts_range = pd.date_range(ts_year_group.index[0][1], 
                         ts_year_group.index[-1][1]+pd.DateOffset(months=1), 
                         freq="M")
ts = pd.DataFrame(ts_year_group.values, 
                  index=ts_range, 
                  columns=ts_year_group.keys())
ts_fullyears_group = ts.groupby(lambda x: x.year)
nin_anomalies = (grouped.mean()['ANOM.3'] - sts.nanmean(grouped.mean()['ANOM.3'])) / sts.nanstd(grouped.mean()['ANOM.3'])

nin_anomalies

1982    1.527215
1983    0.779877
1984   -0.970047
1985   -1.012997
1986    0.193297
1987    1.978809
1988   -1.603259
1989   -1.173755
1990    0.244837
1991    0.967632
1992    0.977449
1993    0.568807
1994    0.617893
1995   -0.270568
1996   -0.684120
1997    1.857320
1998   -0.190803
1999   -1.718612
2000   -1.287880
2001   -0.349106
2002    1.106301
2003    0.466953
2004    0.585987
2005    0.196978
2006    0.273062
2007   -0.751613
2008   -1.060856
2009    0.573715
2010   -0.642396
2011   -1.200752
2012    0.000633
Name: ANOM.3, dtype: float64
```

i'm sure there is better way to do the same :/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, a bit hackish at times since your dates are on the 2nd of each month.

Starts off the same:

```
In [205]: import pandas as pd

In [206]: from datetime import datetime

In [207]: from datetime import timedelta

In [208]: 

In [208]: def parse(yr, mon):
   .....:         date = datetime(year=int(yr), day=2, month=int(mon))
   .....:         return date
   .....: 

In [209]: 

In [209]: url='http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/sstoi.indices'

In [210]: data = pd.read_table(url, sep=' ', header=0, skiprows=0, parse_dates = [['YR', 'MON']], skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0, date_parser=parse)                     

In [211]: grouped = data.groupby(lambda x: x.year)
```

Get the full years:

```
In [212]: full_year = grouped['NINO1+2'].count() == 12

In [213]: full_year
Out[213]: 
1982     True
1983     True
1984     True
1985     True
1986     True
1987     True
1988     True
1989     True
1990     True
1991     True
1992     True
1993     True
1994     True
1995     True
1996     True
1997     True
1998     True
1999     True
2000     True
2001     True
2002     True
2003     True
2004     True
2005     True
2006     True
2007     True
2008     True
2009     True
2010     True
2011     True
2012     True
2013    False
dtype: bool
```

Now we deal with getting the indices in the correct data type and aligned.  This could probably be simplified a bit:

```
In [214]: strt = data.index[0] - timedelta(1)
In [215]: idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=strt, periods=len(full_year - 1), freq='BA-JAN')

In [216]: idx = idx + timedelta(1)  # Get to 2nd of each month

In [232]: idx
Out[232]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1982-01-02 00:00:00, ..., 2013-01-02 00:00:00]
Length: 32, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [233]: full_year.index = idx
```

This is the key step:

```
In [234]: full_year = full_year.reindex_like(data, method='ffill')
```

And hopefully this is correct:

```
In [235]: data.ix[full_year].tail()
Out[235]: 
            NINO1+2  ANOM  NINO3  ANOM.1  NINO4  ANOM.2  NINO3.4  ANOM.3  \
YR_MON                                                                     
2012-08-02    20.99  0.35  25.72    0.73  29.10    0.42    27.55    0.73   
2012-09-02    20.83  0.49  25.28    0.43  29.12    0.43    27.24    0.51   
2012-10-02    20.68 -0.11  24.93    0.01  29.16    0.50    26.98    0.29   
2012-11-02    21.21 -0.38  25.11    0.14  29.17    0.54    27.01    0.36   
2012-12-02    22.13 -0.68  24.91   -0.23  28.71    0.23    26.46   -0.11   

            Unnamed: 10  
YR_MON                   
2012-08-02          NaN  
2012-09-02          NaN  
2012-10-02          NaN  
2012-11-02          NaN  
2012-12-02          NaN
```

Just work on data.ix[full_year] and you should be good to go.