# Removing incomplete years from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove incomplete years from a dataframe to analyse the complete years further. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256294/pandas-dataframe-remove-values-from-a-group-with-less-than-x-rows) but the question is old and unresolved. This post follows on from a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090917/calculating-the-number-of-years-in-a-pandas-dataframe) where some of this code came from.

Dataframe:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=3200)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3200), columns =list ('A'))
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A']]
df.head()

        date         A
0 2007-01-01 -0.961392
1 2007-01-02  0.832136
2 2007-01-03  1.007776
3 2007-01-04 -1.144121
4 2007-01-05 -0.850436
```

Index by year, count the days

```
count = df.set_index([df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.day]).count(level=0)
count

      date    A
date           
2007   365  365
2008   366  366
2009   365  365
2010   365  365
2011   365  365
2012   366  366
2013   365  365
2014   365  365
2015   278  278
```

Drop all the years less than 365 days:

```
count = count.drop(count[count.date < 365].index)
```

I now want to 'uncount' the data so it returns to looking like this:

```
        date         A
0 2007-01-01 -0.961392
1 2007-01-02  0.832136
2 2007-01-03  1.007776
3 2007-01-04 -1.144121
4 2007-01-05 -0.850436
```

but doesn't include 2015 as the year is too short.

## ANSWER

Create a years variable

```
years = count[count['date'] >= 365].index
```

reformat the dataframe

```
df = df[df['date'].dt.year.isin(years)]
df

Out[11]: 
           date         A
0    2007-01-01 -0.095152
1    2007-01-02 -0.560478
2    2007-01-03  0.793423
...    ....    ....   ...
2919 2014-12-29 -1.616931
2920 2014-12-30 -3.499278
2921 2014-12-31  0.913521
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `years` and pass to your original df and call [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) and pass [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html#pandas.Series.dt.year):

```
In [93]:
years = count[count['date'] >= 365].index
df[df['date'].dt.year.isin(years)]

Out[93]:
           date         A
0    2007-01-01  0.020745
1    2007-01-02  0.030024
2    2007-01-03 -0.385793
3    2007-01-04 -0.737720
4    2007-01-05  0.089707
5    2007-01-06 -0.820141
6    2007-01-07 -0.081740
7    2007-01-08  0.233265
8    2007-01-09  1.336224
9    2007-01-10  0.570297
10   2007-01-11 -0.280080
11   2007-01-12 -1.582950
12   2007-01-13  0.494927
13   2007-01-14  2.065250
14   2007-01-15 -2.406877
15   2007-01-16  0.124046
16   2007-01-17 -1.015604
17   2007-01-18  1.480173
18   2007-01-19  0.705919
19   2007-01-20 -2.014657
20   2007-01-21  0.130874
21   2007-01-22 -0.138736
22   2007-01-23  1.874702
23   2007-01-24 -0.170154
24   2007-01-25 -1.548015
25   2007-01-26 -0.878455
26   2007-01-27 -0.871497
27   2007-01-28  1.992482
28   2007-01-29  0.565247
29   2007-01-30  1.257662
...         ...       ...
2892 2014-12-02 -1.052277
2893 2014-12-03  0.123017
2894 2014-12-04 -0.970947
2895 2014-12-05 -0.821208
2896 2014-12-06 -0.027118
2897 2014-12-07 -0.100033
2898 2014-12-08  0.954733
2899 2014-12-09  0.388998
2900 2014-12-10  0.667443
2901 2014-12-11  1.580804
2902 2014-12-12  0.724011
2903 2014-12-13 -2.156507
2904 2014-12-14  0.736236
2905 2014-12-15  0.863674
2906 2014-12-16 -0.204992
2907 2014-12-17  0.976307
2908 2014-12-18  1.456367
2909 2014-12-19 -0.516854
2910 2014-12-20 -0.140291
2911 2014-12-21  1.467225
2912 2014-12-22  0.957542
2913 2014-12-23  2.061477
2914 2014-12-24  0.202104
2915 2014-12-25  0.806140
2916 2014-12-26 -0.478380
2917 2014-12-27  1.109158
2918 2014-12-28 -0.598417
2919 2014-12-29 -1.283922
2920 2014-12-30  0.546390
2921 2014-12-31 -0.640812

[2922 rows x 2 columns]
```

This will filter the df so that only those dates with full complement of days remain