# Removing incomplete seasons from multi-index dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to apply the method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157738/removing-incomplete-years-from-pandas-dataframe) to a multi-index dataframe, doesn't seem to work.

Take a data-frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=3200)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,100,(3200,1)), columns =list('A'))
df['A'][5,6,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] = np.nan #add missing data points
df['date'] = dates
df = df[['date','A']]
```

Apply season function to the datetime index

```
def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return '2'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return '3'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return '4'
    else:
        return '1'
```

Apply the function

```
df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
```

Create a 'Year' column for indexing

```
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

Multi-index by Year and Season

```
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)
```

Count datapoints in each season

```
count = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).count()
```

Drop the seasons with less than 75 days in them

```
count = count.drop(count[count.A < 75].index)
```

Create a variable for seasons with more than 75 days

```
complete = count[count['A'] >= 75].index
```

Using isin function turns up false for everything, while I want it to select all the seasons who have more than 75 days of valid data in 'A'

```
df = df.isin(complete)
df
```

Every value comes up false, and I can't see why.

I hope this is concise enough, I need this to work on a multi-index using seasons so I included it!

**EDIT**

Another method based on multi-index reindexing not working (which also produces a blank dataframe) from [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7895)

```
df3 = df.reset_index().groupby('Year').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Season').reindex(count,method='pad'))
```

**EDIT 2**

Also tried this

```
seasons = count[count['A'] >= 75].index

df = df[df['A'].isin(seasons)]
```

Again, blank output

Comment: I think 'rain' should be 'A'?

Comment: I suspect you wanted to do something like this?  `count = df[ df.A > 75 ].groupby(level=[0, 1]).count()`.  That gives you a count of days > 75.  After that I suspect you want to use merge or join, not isin.

Comment: @John Yes it should be 'A' - sorry about that.

Comment: @johnE sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. I don't want to count the number of days with values above 75 - I want to count the number of days in each season, and if there are more than 75 days in each season, I want to keep it. If there are less than 75 days in each season, I want to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
complete = count[count['A'] >= 75].index 


idx = df.index.isin(complete)
print idx
[ True  True  True ..., False False False]

print df[idx]
```

```
                 date     A
Year Season                 
2007 1      2007-01-01  24.0
     1      2007-01-02  92.0
     1      2007-01-03  54.0
     1      2007-01-04  91.0
     1      2007-01-05  91.0
     1      2007-01-06   NaN
     1      2007-01-07   NaN
     1      2007-01-08   NaN
     1      2007-01-09   NaN
     1      2007-01-10   NaN
     1      2007-01-11   NaN
     1      2007-01-12   NaN
     1      2007-01-13   NaN
     1      2007-01-14   NaN
     1      2007-01-15  18.0
     1      2007-01-16  82.0
     1      2007-01-17  55.0
     1      2007-01-18  64.0
     1      2007-01-19  89.0
     1      2007-01-20  37.0
     1      2007-01-21  45.0
     1      2007-01-22   4.0
     1      2007-01-23  34.0
     1      2007-01-24  35.0
     1      2007-01-25  90.0
     1      2007-01-26  17.0
     1      2007-01-27  29.0
     1      2007-01-28  58.0
     1      2007-01-29   7.0
     1      2007-01-30  57.0
...                ...   ...
2015 3      2015-08-02  42.0
     3      2015-08-03   0.0
     3      2015-08-04  31.0
     3      2015-08-05  39.0
     3      2015-08-06  25.0
     3      2015-08-07   1.0
     3      2015-08-08   7.0
     3      2015-08-09  97.0
     3      2015-08-10  38.0
     3      2015-08-11  59.0
     3      2015-08-12  28.0
     3      2015-08-13  84.0
     3      2015-08-14  43.0
     3      2015-08-15  63.0
     3      2015-08-16  68.0
     3      2015-08-17   0.0
     3      2015-08-18  19.0
     3      2015-08-19  61.0
     3      2015-08-20  11.0
     3      2015-08-21  84.0
     3      2015-08-22  75.0
     3      2015-08-23  37.0
     3      2015-08-24  40.0
     3      2015-08-25  66.0
     3      2015-08-26  50.0
     3      2015-08-27  74.0
     3      2015-08-28  37.0
     3      2015-08-29  19.0
     3      2015-08-30  25.0
     3      2015-08-31  15.0

[3106 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, this identifies the correct variables with 'True' and 'False' (the first season is 'False' as it has so many missing values). But when I apply it using `print idx[df]` it just returns the entire dataframe and doesn't omit the seasons with less than 75 days.

Comment: Hmmm if I `print df` it has 3200 row, if `print df[idx]` it has 3106 rows. So I think 94 rows is removed. But I dont know how I can check it better. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't restarted the kernel and there was a glitch in one of the variables, this does work, thanks!